# How to scroll to an element using react-spring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-spring

I have read through the entire `react-spring` docs and there doesn't seem to be a clear way to do this.

My attempt:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from "react"
import { animated, useSpring } from "react-spring"

const App = () => {
    const scrollDestinationRef = useRef()

    const [elementScroll, setElementScroll] = useState(false)

    const buttonClickHandler = () => setElementScroll(prevState => !prevState)

    const scrollAnimation = useSpring({
        scroll: elementScroll
            ? scrollDestinationRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top
            : 0
    })

    return (
        <main>
            {/* Click to scroll to destination */}
            <animated.button
                onClick={buttonClickHandler}
                scrollTop={scrollAnimation.scroll}
                style={{
                    height: "1000px",
                    width: "100%",
                    backgroundColor: "tomato"
                }}
            >
                Scroll to destination
            </animated.button>

            {/* Scroll destination */}
            <div
                ref={scrollDestinationRef}
                style={{
                    height: "200px",
                    width: "200px",
                    backgroundColor: "green"
                }}
            ></div>
        </main>
    )
}

export default App
```

I'm using a ref and hooks for my attempt.

The `useRef` is attached the scroll destination in-order to find its offset top from the website's ceiling.

I use `useState` to toggle between the state on click to trigger the scroll.

I use `useSpring` to trigger an animation that goes from 0 to the scroll destination's scroll top a.k.a. `getBoundingClientRect().top`.

Can anyone assist in solving this?

There doesn't to be much explanation online, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

`useSpring` returns a function to set/update animated values. You can use that function to assign a new value to your animated variable. Then, you can use the `onFrame` property to update the scroll position.

Define your `spring` like this:

```
const [y, setY] = useSpring(() => ({
    immediate: false,
    y: 0,
    onFrame: props => {
      window.scroll(0, props.y);
    },
    config: config.slow,
  }));
```

Then use `setY` function to start the spring, like this:

```
 <button
        onClick={() => {
          setY({ y: scrollDestinationRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().top });
        }}
      >
        Click to scroll
 </button>
```

When you click the button it will assign a new value to `y` variable in your spring, and `onFrame` function will be called upon every update.

Note that we call `window.scroll` function from `onFrame` property in `useSpring`.

**See working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-rrtsmt?file=index.js).**

Comment: Thank you very much. When you scroll up and down after pressing the button once upon load, it no longer works. It only works the first time. Can you amend this please?

Answer (score 2):

Finally after getting through https://github.com/pmndrs/react-spring/issues/544, answer from Yannick Schuchmann here worked for me, I just had to change onFrame to onChange

I made a custom hook for the solution: https://github.com/TomasSestak/react-spring-scroll-to-hook

react-sring version: 9.0.0-rc.3

Comment: Updated for react-spring 9+ on the same link

Comment: Thank you, for now I'm using your project!

Answer (score 1):

```
const targetElement = useRef(null)
const [, setY] = useSpring(() => ({ y: 0 }))

let isStopped = false
const onWheel = () => {
  isStopped = true
  window.removeEventListener('wheel', onWheel)
}

const scrollToTarget = () => {
  const element = targetElement.current
  const value = window.scrollY + element.getBoundingClientRect().top

  window.addEventListener('wheel', onWheel)

  setY({
    y: value,
    reset: true,
    from: { y: window.scrollY },
    onRest: () => {
      isStopped = false
      window.removeEventListener('wheel', onWheel)
    },
    onFrame: props => {
      if (!isStopped) {
        window.scroll(0, props.y)
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This version also allows the user to break out of the forced scrolling by using `wheel` event. (I personally hate forced scrolling :D)

`useSpring(fn)` does return a `stop` method besides the `set`. But I couldn't make it work with that. I posted it to a related [github issue](https://github.com/react-spring/react-spring/issues/544#issuecomment-540661109). If you read this, maybe there's a good answer for that already :)

For now it uses a little workaround with `isStopped` flag.

---

**UPDATE:**

Seems like there is actually something fishy with `stop` fn which should be addressed in [v9 canary](https://spectrum.chat/react-spring/general/try-the-new-v9-canary~c5cad1eb-c6ff-4b40-9a10-76d368c3e404). Haven't tested since v9 is not stable yet.